# Are all positive operators Hermitian?

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products, hermitian-matrices

> A special subclass of Hermitian operators is extremely important. This is the positive
> operators. A positive operator A is defined to be an operator such that for any vector $|v\rangle$,
> $(|v\rangle, A|v\rangle)$ is a real, non-negative number.

$(|v\rangle, A|v\rangle)$ refers to the inner product/dot product between $|v\rangle$ and $A|v\rangle$

I saw this bit of info in a quantum computing book. It made sense to me at first, Hermitian operators had real eigenvalues, positive operators had real positive eigenvalues. Until it didn't... I just found a positive matrix which isn't Hermitian:

\begin{equation*}
A = 
\begin{bmatrix}
3 & 1 \\
0 & 2
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation*}

If we visualize this in "3b1b essence of linear algebra" style, we can see that none of the vectors get flipped around enough, so $(|v\rangle, A|v\rangle)$ is never negative. So it should be a positive operator... But $A^T\neq A$, so it's not Hermitian.

What's wrong here?

Comment: Short answer, no. Also, $A\implies B$ doesn't mean that $B\implies A$.

Comment: That matrix is not positive: take $v = (1,\text i)$

Comment: So judging by the 2 different comments above, in the real numbers not all positive operators are Hermitian (symmetric in this case), but in the complex numbers they are?

Comment: Yes, and no. A real matrix is also a complex matrix. But the definition for a real matrix usually assumes $v$ is real. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Definite_matrix#Consistency_between_real_and_complex_definitions

Comment: You may look at the statements there: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positive_operator_(Hilbert_space)

Comment: In quantum computing, the vector spaces are almost universally assumed to be finite-dimensional vector spaces over the complex numbers, so you need to include complex numbers in that context.